# c++ heap allocations 32 byte aligned by default?

Tags: c++

i decided to test the memory consumption with Visual Studio 2013 Community edition, and noticed that on my computer the memory consumption skyrocketed when using pointers, for example:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto n = 1000000;

    std::vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.reserve(n);

    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++){
        numbers.emplace_back(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get 4 bytes per int, for a total of 3.8MB, which i can corroborate via task Manager.

But if i decide to change the `std::vector<int>` for `std::vector<int*>`:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto n = 1000000;

    std::vector<int*> numbers;
    numbers.reserve(n);

    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++){
        numbers.emplace_back(new int(0));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I suddenly get the original 3.8MB which indicate pointers in my computer are 4 bytes, plus 30.5MB which indicates every new int() used 32 bytes, incurring 28 bytes of overhead per int.

If i change the raw pointer to std::unique_ptr it uses the same memory as expected, but changing to std::shared_ptr (without using std::make_shared) it adds an extra 42MB because of the extra pointer and variables.

All this got me by surprise, i know it is not a realistic example to use that many pointers to primitives, but since large applications tend to use a lot of pointers i was wondering if this means that it should always be expected that heap allocations will use a minimum of 32 bytes? or is that configurable somewhere on visual studio or is it platform dependent?

If so, is there a way to debug and see how much unused overhead our program has on the heap? that would be helpful in deciding when to use custom allocation, my example can easily be fixed to use 7.6MB instead of 34.3MB by allocating the memory beforehand and using placement new for example.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing 32bit or 64bit app?

Comment: Might be valuable to compare to a release build. In debug MSVC adds padding to the beginning and end of each allocation to check for buffer overruns. But each allocation also incurs some overhead even in release.

Comment: Could you set _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 environment variable and check memory again? Do not run app under debugger

Comment: Forgot to mention, i was using release version while checking the memory consumption, will try with _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1, and let you know the results, i am using 64bit OS, but i didn't selected anything 64 bit related while creating the project.

Comment: No change with _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1, but i decided to run the exe outside Visual Studio and noticed much lower consumption, this way the allocations where 16 bytes aligned, so the 32 bytes should be caused by visual studio overhead even in release mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat to be expected. The standard allocators typically guarantee some level of alignment for the start of each allocation. This allows for mechanical sympathy around caching, and is generally a good thing, as aligned accesses often execute much faster than unaligned ones.

Also allocations with MSVC in debug builds typically include guard bytes before and after the area allocated, increasing the size significantly, especially for small allocations like yours.